# Pass JSON from flask to template and decode html entity

Tags: python, html, json, flask, character-encoding

So I have been stuck on this for a while. I have a MongoDB that i query and return as JSON.

I do this by:

```
bson.json_utils.dumps(list(all_exams.find(query))
```

I then pass this into a flask template variable to use in an inline js script in HTML.

```
<div id="results">
  <table id="results-table">
  </table>
  <p>
     {{results_json}}
  </p>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$('#results-table').dynatable({
dataset: {
  records: {{results_json}}
}
});
</script>
```

The problem is that in the script, the JSON cannot be parsed by denotable properly because it contains `&#34;` That is the entity value for a double quote but shouldn't it not appear like that if i inspect the source code. Shouldn't the html page display it as an `"`. This only happens in the script section. Not in the `<p>` tag (that prints out all `&#34;` as `"`).

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid XSS attacks, flask and other template languages escape values by default: it converts `"` into the HTML entity so that the browser reads it as text to be displayed for humans rather than the part of the HTML syntax (e.g. `<a href="...">`). This happens in all tags: inside the `<p>` tag you see the quote in your browser but the source code is still the entity.

To tell flask to not escape stuff, use `{{results_json | safe}}`. That's you asserting that the value is safe, not telling flask to make it safe (which is what it was doing before).

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been stuck on this for way too long!

Comment: Thank you very much!